# is there any better approach to sync data from Bigquery to singlestore throgh pipelines?

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, singlestore

I have data in the Bigquery table and wanted to sync it to singlestore table. I can see the singlestore pipeline documentation here https://docs.singlestore.com/db/v7.8/en/reference/sql-reference/pipelines-commands/create-pipeline.html. it has options to use GCS to load data from. it seems like it expects files from google cloud. I am new to singlestore, can somebody suggest a better approach. should I use pipelines or not? I have created a query stream from Bigquery and now want to insert data to singlestore DB in Nodejs. can we use write stream to singlestore? can we use the pipeline to insert records via the above stream from BQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to perform batch data movement from BigQuery to SingleStoreDB would be to perform exports of the data to GCS and use Pipelines to pull the data into SingleStoreDB. Pipelines are optimized for loading data into SingleStoreDB in parallel. If you export the data in Avro format, it will be even more efficient on both sides. It will likely be less complex and more efficient than trying to build the same workflow in Node.js.

Comment: thanks for the reply, this approach looks good to me. but I have a Question. so, it will export all data every time to GCS, and then it will load all data every time to single-store right? so, if I want to remove old data from SS after every successful data load, how i can do it? or can I export only the data which is newly added? or can I add any new fields while exporting data like updatedAt? if I write a nodejs job then I can manually insert the records to the SS with newly field added and can remove old records easily

Comment: You can use the EXPORT DATA statement in BigQuery to export the results of a query. So if you have a timestamp field that you can use to export incremental data rather than doing a full export every time. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements

Comment: You can also set up a SingleStoreDB PIPELINE to load the data into a stored procedure in which you can do all sorts of additional processing of the data, like adding new fields or even assessing which records should be inserted into the SingleStoreDB table. https://docs.singlestore.com/managed-service/en/reference/sql-reference/pipelines-commands/create-pipeline-----into-procedure.html

Comment: I set SingleStoreDB PIPELINE, It is really good in terms of performance and also, and I have created a setup for updating the existing records based on the primary key combination